# Ajax call does not refreshesh the calling page javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a JSP page that refreshes every 5 seconds Using ajax.
The page i am calling having javascript that is not getting refreshed .
Please tell me how to achieve that.

Below is the code i am using to refresh that page .

refresh is the name of the div where i am displaying the data.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function AutoRefresh(){
                var xmlHttp;
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                }
                catch (e){
                    try{
                        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
                    }
                    catch (e){
                        try{
                            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch (e){
                            alert("No AJAX");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    //alert("hi");
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){

                        document.getElementById('TotalRoutes').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;

                        setTimeout('AutoRefresh()',10*1000); // JavaScript function calls AutoRefresh() every 3 seconds
                    }
                }
                xmlHttp.open("GET","QAGENIE.jsp",true);

                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
        </script>
```

Here js files in the QAGENIE.jsp page is not getting refreshed on the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap that code inside `$(document).ready();`

like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8088/Login.do', 
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#refresh").html(data);
                    alert(data);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert("refresh");
                    setTimeout(function(){ worker(); },5000);
                    //$('#refresh').load("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js");
                }

            });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

you should import the jquery file first

like

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/view/js/jquery1.7.2.js"></script>
```

and debug is，if is nothing in you console，it will be success